# How to create password system in tkinter reading the data from file

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, tkinter-entry

I want to create password system in tkinter with notepad as my DB which contains the data in my working directory but when I insert data in the entry fields I receive an error login failed.Have created the txt file but it seems the function can't read from the file.Any suggestion on how to do this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox


now = open("passdoc.txt","w+")
now.write("user\n")
now.write("python3")
now.close()

def login_in():
    with open("passdoc.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == new[0] in passdoc.txt and entry2.get() == new[1] in 
passdoc.txt:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")


def close():
    log.destroy() #Removes toplevel window
    root.destroy() #Removes  root window
    sys.exit() #Ends the script


root=tk.Tk()
log = tk.Toplevel() #

root.geometry("350x350")
log.geometry("200x200")

entry1 = tk.Entry(log) #Username entry
entry2 = tk.Entry(log) #Password entry
button1 = tk.Button(log, text="Login", command=login_in) #Login button
button2 = tk.Button(log, text="Cancel", command=close) #Cancel button
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="tkinter password system")

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
label1.place(x=30,y=300)


label = tk.Label(root, text="welcome").pack()

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

## I created this functions too but all seems not to work out for me

```
def login_in():
    with open("passdoc.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == name in passdoc.txt and entry2.get() == password in 
passdoc.txt:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("errror","login failed")    #error login failed 
(corrections)
```

Comment: have you tried to check what does name and password contains when you press the button? You can check by adding print statements right below those two lines.

Comment: Also, your if statement is plain wrong. You should get NameError at that line with this given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things in your code that need some work but the main issue is in your `login_in()` function.

Your `if` statement is all wrong. I am not sure why you wrote it the way you did but lets fix it.

Because you defined `name = new[0].rstrip()` and `password = new[1].rstrip()`
you can use `name` and `password` to verify if the user has enter the correct credentials.

So your `if` statement should look like this:

```
if entry1.get() == name and entry2.get() == password:
```

Your use of `in passdoc.txt` does not do anything and cannot work because `passdoc.txt` to python looks like an undefined variable and would fail on the if statement. Remember that you imported all the contents of `passdoc.txt` as `f` so you didn't create a variable named `passdoc` you created one named `f` for the `with open()` statement

If you wanted to shorten your code a little you could remove `name` and `password` variables and just write the if statement with `new`

So your `login_in()` function could look like either this:

```
def login_in():
    with open("passdoc.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == name and entry2.get() == password:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")
```

Or this:

```
def login_in():
    with open("passdoc.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
    if entry1.get() == new[0].rstrip() and entry2.get() == new[1].rstrip():
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections ,this will surely guide in future.